# How to merge an updated branch into local branch

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull-request

I pushed my local branch to remote on GitHub, and another person made a commit in the branch. I also made commits locally, and when I tried to push it again, it got rejected saying "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind".
The question is how can I merge the remote commit into my local branch without deleting the commit I made on my local branch, and push it again.

Comment: just pull it, do any merges locally, then push it again.. Much more info here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin <branch> && git push origin <branch>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: Note that there is no *accepted* answer on the duplicate, but if you scroll through them there are two answers with very high upvote counts and both are good.